# Interenet shop. Ubercart on Drupal 6 or Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

I plan to start creating tomorrow interenet shop (Ubercart). I'd like to take the 7 version - lots of nice things. Can you tell me now start to create on drupal 7 or can only work with Drupal 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drupal 7 version of Ubercart is in [alpha status](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) currently. It's generally a bad idea to use alpha software in a production site, but if you plan on developing for a couple months you'll probably be okay. If you plan to launch in a week, version 7 probably isn't for you.

Comment: Very sorry, but I have time, less than a month.
Thanks for the advice.